# Add a constraint to a gobbing route parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, routes, constraints

I have the following route:

```
get lib/2/subscriber:*params, to: 'lib2#subscriber_req'
```

I want a constraint that this route would match only if `params` is `/\d+\//`. I want it to match

```
lib/2/subscriber:1256/bla/blabla
```

but not

```
lib/2/subscriber:some_text1256/bla/blabla
```

I read [this](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#route-globbing-and-wildcard-segments) document. I wrote this route:

```
get lib/2/subscriber:*params, to: 'lib2#subscriber_req', , constraints:{params: /\d+\//}
```

But it doesn't work.

In general I don't know how to handle the GLOBS constraints. Some links would very helpful.

Comment: Is `, ,` valid in Ruby code?

Comment: What is your question? If you are asking for links, then this question would be off topic.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get why you thought that `/\d+\//` would differentiate between:

- `lib/2/subscriber:1256/bla/blabla`
- `lib/2/subscriber:some_text1256/bla/blabla`

They both match that regex. If you want to match the `params` part of the first URL but not that of the second one, then perhaps this would work:

```
/\A\d+\//
```